# How to remember image path which applies to imageview box

Tags: android, imageview, gallery

Iam developing a simple app in which a button is pressed to choose image from gallery which applies to image view box but problem is how to remember the image path that whenever i exit and reopens app the same image should appears in image view box.

[image]

```
 <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image1"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:src="@drawable/index"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"

                />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use shared prefs

on image selection

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("ImagePrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString("imagePath", myImagePath);
editor.commit();
```

then when you start the app up

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("ImagePrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
if(sharedpreferences.contains("imagePath")) // we have an image
{
   String path = sharedpreferences.getString("imagePath")
   //here set the image from the path
}
else
{
  //no image was ever selected
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works. But image with larger file size takes time to load as compare to smaller one.